# Missing Layer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, gdal, geotiff-tiff

When I try to include the "fwp layer" from geoserver 2.4 (Ubuntu 12.4 VServer) into my code it doesn't show up. But the geoserver layer preview (OL) shows the right image.
The GeoExplorer preview shows only pink tiles with a questionnmark.

The fwp layer is a Geotiff file which I had transformed with 
`gdaladdo -r average FWP_neun1.tif 2 4 8 16`

Here is the actually website: [WEB GIS](http://gis.neunkirchen.gv.at/nkgis_03.10.html) where it should work.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution: just changed the image format form png to gif. :-)